# How does float relate to absolute and relative div positioning?

Tags: html, css-float, css-position

I asked an earlier question about [absolute and relative div positioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8599929/how-does-relative-and-absolute-positioning-work-with-embedded-divs), but I would like to try to understand (for sure) the role of `float` in this context.

My main question is: how does `float` relate to `absolute` and `relative` `div` positioning?

Are the following statements correct (yes/no):

1. `float right` (or `left`) will try to stack all `div` one after the other starting from `right` (or `left`). If there is not enough space (`width` issue), the `div`s are displayed at the next 'line' (from top to bottom).
2. `float` does not impact `absolute div` ever, `absolute` overrides `float`
3. `relative div` are positioned relatively to the first enclosing `relative div` (`absolute div`s are ignored)
4. `float right` (or `left`) on a `div` will first compute what would be the natural position of a `relative div`, then add any top-left offset to compute the final position.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/  7,8 and 9

> With CSS float, an element can be pushed to the left or right,
>   allowing other elements to wrap around it.

The statements you provided 'appear' correct

Comment: Well statement 3 is false... relative positioning does not depend on the fact the enclosing is relative or not.

Answer (score 6):

Float left or right will site next to each other inline unless the width are 100% then they would sit under neath each other:

[image]

Hope this makes sense and is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

An absolutely positioned division is only relevant to the first ancestor element whose position is not static, which is how it determines where it ends up via it's top, right, bottom, left properties. An absolutely positioned element cannot be floated because it has been removed from the flow of the document.

I'm confused about your point #3, which doesn't make much sense. A relative division would render the division as it would normally appear in the document. It can then be moved around with its top, left, bottom, right properties while **still maintaining** the same position it *would have* used had it not been moved anywhere. A relatively positioned element can be floated like any normal element and will not affect where other floated elements end up when you move it around.